# Javascript Regex to colorize a div

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been looking for the Javascript Regex to accomplish the following modifications to a div content :

- Find quoted strings ("" or '') and color them in red
- Find keywords (pre-defined) and color them in yellow
- Find special-quoted strings (``) and dot-preceded strings (.string) and color them in blue.

Since I'm working in a HTML document, here would be the regex input :

```
keyword string.name keyword `name` string keyword "quoted" string 'another quote'
```

And the output should be :

```
<span class="keyword">keyword</span>
 string
 <span class="name">.name</span>
 <span class="keyword">keyword</span>
 <span class="name">`name`</span>
 string
 <span class="keyword">keyword</span>
 <span class="quote">"quoted"</span>
 string
 <span class="quote">'another quote'</span>
```

The first problem comes when some characters match *more than one* of the models : If I have "ON" in my keywords and some quoted text contains "ON", It should go red and not yellow.
The order of importance is **["']quotes["'] > `names` > keywords > .names**

The second problem comes with quotes : the `class=""` itself contains a *quote*.

I have some regexes, but this doesn't handle multiple-match nor quotes correctly...

```
input.replace(/(["'])((\\{2})*|(.*?[^\\](\\{2})*))\1/g, '<span class="quote">$&</span>') //For the quotes (doesn't work correctly)
input.replace(/KEYWORD1|KEYWORD2|...|LASTKEYWORD/g, '<span class="kw">$&</span>') //For the keywords (Quite explicit)
input.replace(/`[\.\n]*`/g, '<span class="name">$&</span>') //For the `names`
input.replace(/(\w*)(\.\w*)/g, '<span class="name">$&</span>') //For the .names
```

Does anyone have a solution **In Javascript** ?
I could be a parser function as well as a monster regex, I don't really care, as long as it works.

Comment: Don't use regex. Use a parser / finite-state machine / lexer to work through the string.

Comment: What if you just parse the string, instead of using a regex?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I'll look for that, and edit the post as needed. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: Well, I couldn't find anything useful in regex nor with parsing functions.